# Map a Java UserPrincipal to an Active Directory user

Tags: java, jndi, nio2

I am accessing a remote server with Java. The server runs Microsoft Windows and provides an Active Directory as well as a file system share. I read users and groups from the Active Directory via JNDI, which works great. I get all user attributes like `distinguishedName`, `objectSid` and so on.

My Java program also connects to a Windows share on the same server, using Java 7 and NIO.2. I can read the remote file system and get information about it. I can also read file permission settings like this:

```
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.attribute.AclEntry;
    import java.nio.file.attribute.AclFileAttributeView;
    import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal;

    [...]

    AclFileAttributeView aclView = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, AclFileAttributeView.class);

    for (AclEntry aclEntry : aclView.getAcl()) {
        UserPrincipal principal = aclEntry.principal();
        [...]
    }
```

This way I get access rights for a `UserPrincipal` object. This class only provides a method `getName()` which returns some name or sometimes an SID.

For actual users the `UserPrincipal` object returns an SID which I can use to find the corresponding user in the Active Directory. However, if `UserPrincipal` represents a group, `getName()` just returns a text like for example `"VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren"`.

I could not find a way to map this text to a group defined in the Active Directory. The corresponding group in AD has this `distinguishedName` property: `CN=Administratoren,CN=Builtin,DC=mydomain,DC=com`.

Both the machine where the Java program runs and the server are running a German version of Windows. It's strange that AD returns `CN=Builtin` (English) but the file system returns a group name with a German translation `VORDEFINIERT`. If both would be e.g. `Builtin` I could probably parse the `UserPrincipal` and find out what the `distinguishedName` of the AD object should be... however, this approach does not seem to be very reliable.

I'd really like to be able to read the SID of all `UserPrincipal` objects so that I can find the corresponding user or group in AD.

Is there a way to do this? Please let me know if you need more information.

Best regards,
sky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I continued researching this problem and found a solution:

In this case (accessing a Windows share) the objects returned by `aclEntry.principal()` are actually of class `WindowsUserPrincipals.Group` or `WindowsUserPrincipals.User`. `UserPrincipal` is an interface implemented by `WindowsUserPrincipals.User`. And `WindowsUserPrincipals.Group` is a subclass of `WindowsUserPrincipals.User`.

Class `sun.nio.fs.WindowsUserPrincipals` is not public, so it can't be accessed directly. But I saw that the inner class `WindowsUserPrincipals.User` contains exactly the SID which I have been looking for. It is in a private field called `sidString`.

So my solution is to check if the returned `UserPrincipal` is a `WindowsUserPrincipal` and if yes, use reflection to read the value of field `sidString`.

It works and can be written in a reliable way, however, it is not a really super nice solution because I had to use reflection. But I did not find an easier way to access or get the SID.

Please still answer this question if you know better ways to read the SID. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sky!
I am reserching approach to implement something similar what you did and I wonder if your implementation is still alive after 2 years? Maybe you found more reliable way to match AD users/groups with users/groups from AclFileAttributeView?

Comment: @VolodymyrKrupach Yes, it was working reliably and has been used in an production environment for about 2 years now without issues. Seen that it worked well and that I didn't get any further input, I didn't research the topic any further and therefore didn't find any other ways to do that.